# Vector Bender in QGIS 3.10 not aligning

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector

I am using the Vector Bender plugin to "georeference" a shapefile to a raster to point file. When I run the processes following this tutorial, my polygons are still not moving even though no errors were detected. Am I doing something wrong?

Vector Bender Plugin Interface:

[image]

Snapping Polygon To Raster to Point File:
[image]

Turning "plant_counts2" Editor On:
[image]

Running With No Problems:
[image]

No Changes:
[image]

Comment: Are both your raster and shapefile in a projected coordinate system?

Comment: They are both in WGS84 zone 10, yes. They however do have different extents.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, but I ended up using the Vector Geometry Rotate tool and rotated around a chosen centroid. I also had to ignore invalid geometries. Not sure if that's why the other tool wasn't working??

Comment: Try doing it with only two points rather than four - and make sure each point is as far apart as possible (say one all the way to the east and one all the way ot the west) I find I don't always have good results with 3+ points in Vector Bender as it bends rather than affines

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Vector Bender Layer is on the same Coordinate System as the layers on your project.
When creating a "Pair Layer" using the plugin interface - the Coordinate System of this new layer is expected to respect project's CRS, but it doesn't.